# Changing path information with PHP

Tags: php, path

Let's say I have a windows path name "E:\Dropbox\b\c\d", when I want to change this path to UNIX with some modifications, I can use this python code.

```
x = "E:\\Dropbox\\b\\c\\d"
print "/Users/prosseek/" + '/'.join(x.split('\\')[1:])

>> /Users/prosseek/Dropbox/b/c/d
```

What could be the equivalent code in PHP?

Comment: didn't you mean `>> /Users/prosseek/Dropbox/b/c/d` (mind the **b**)?

Comment: @hakre : Yes, \b was regarded as control command and python just skipped it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. You could use `explode` and `implode`, but there's no real reason to get fancy and use arrays when this is just a basic string operation:

```
$x = 'E:\Dropbox\b\c\d';
echo '/Users/prosseek/' . str_replace('\\', '/', substr($x, strpos($x, '\\') + 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = "E:\Dropbox\b\c\d";
$unix = str_replace('E:', '/Users/prosseek', $str);
$unix = str_replace('\\', '/', $unix);
```

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/bfa04/2)

Comment: I need to replace "E:" with "/Users/prosseek/" also.

Answer (score 1):

A pretty much exact equivalent of that Python code would be:

```
$x = 'E:\\Dropbox\\b\\c\\d';
echo "/Users/prosseek" . implode('/', explode('\\', substr($x, 2)));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the *exact* PHP equivalent:

```
$x = 'E:\Dropbox\b\c\d';

$parts = explode('\\', $x);

array_shift($parts);

print "/Users/prosseek/" . implode('/', $parts);
```

<strike>However,</strike> this does <strike>not</strike> create the output you wanted. [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QK0O0u).